# Flashing an LED with Schmitt trigger

Tags: led, prototyping, schmitt-trigger, passive-components, protoboard

[image]

I'm trying to build the above circuit, which is supposed to flash an LED with a schmitt trigger (with the possibility to vary the frequency with the knob of the 
 47kOhm potentiometer). I don't have a 12V lamp so I replaced it with a red LED. I added it in series with a 1K resistor. The rest is exactly as on the picture.

When I turn on the power, the LED comes on with one intensity and stays like that. Also no matter where I turn the knob of the potentiometer, the intensity of the LED stays the same.

I've triple, quadruple, quintouple checked my connections and they're correct.

Please help. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I have a 9v 0.45A on hand, but it doesn't even turn on with the upper configuration.

Comment: actually that circuit is supposed to flash a 0.6W incandescent lamp,

Comment: if you have a LED where the lamp is drawn add 470 ohms in series with the led and 220 ohms parallel with that new resistor and the led

Comment: @Jasen that still doesn't make it a relaxation Osc. which relies on the PTC effects of tungsten and size , power and voltage rating of bulb,  Better to use a Schmitt logic Inverter and power FET if necessary with 10M feedback pot and Cap input to Gnd for RC=T

Comment: I'm not convinced that circuit works all that well even with a lamp.

Comment: You cannot replace an incandescent lamp with a LED and resistor, the two act quite differently. You have seriously modified the current flow. Look for an LED flasher.